# Import pandas returning error message in R

Tags: python, r, pandas, reticulate

Trying to import pandas using reticulate in. This is what I have tried writing

```
system("virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3 /home/andres/.virtualenvs/py3-virtualenv")
use_virtualenv("py3-virtualenv")
py_install("pandas",envname="py3-virtualenv")
p <- import("pandas")
```

However this returns the error message

Error in py_module_import(module, convert = convert) :
 ImportError: Unable to import required dependencies:
numpy:

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

```
Importing the numpy c-extensions failed.
- Try uninstalling and reinstalling numpy.
- If you have already done that, then:
 1. Check that you expected to use Python3.8 from "C:\Program Files\RStudio\bin\rsession.exe",
    and that you have no directories in your PATH or PYTHONPATH that can
    interfere with the Python and numpy version "1.17.3" you're trying to use.
 2. If (1) looks fine, you can open a new issue at
    https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues.  Please include details on:
    - how you installed Python
    - how you installed numpy
    - your operating system
    - whether or not you have multiple versions of Python installed
    - if you built from source, your compiler versions and ideally a build log

- If you're working with a numpy git repository, try `git clean -xdf`
 (removes all files not under version control) and
```

I'm not entirely sure what I should do

Comment: If you activate this virtual environment from bash and open python, can you import numpy? Or, laternatively, once you activate the virtual environment, can you see numpy if you do `pip freeze | grep numpy`?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. To answer the questions in the comment above — yes, `numpy` is there in the virtual environment. It can be imported without any issue from within Python.